# Solving a simple system of equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given the simultaneous equations $$A\cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)} + B\sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)} = 0$$ $$A\cos{(2\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}+B\sin{(2\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)} = 0$$ We want to show this has not trivial solutions (ie. solutions when $A\not=0$ and $B\not= 0$). In my notes I have that this gives non-trivial solutions when $$\sin{(2\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}\cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)} - \cos{(2\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}\sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}  = 0$$ but can't quite see why. Can someone explain, thanks.

Comment: Double-angle formulas look promising...

Comment: Double-angle formulas would be useful for transforming the last equation into something more informative, but it's not the best way of getting the equation in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the system
$$Au+Bv=0$$
$$Aw+Bz=0$$
has a non-trivial solution, then
$$u=-\frac{Bv}A=\frac{Avw}{Az}=\frac{vw}z$$
Therefore,
$$uz-vw=0$$

*Remark*: The case $z=0$ must be considered in a different but easy way.

Comment: Just in case OP does not know about determinants.

Answer (score 6):

A system
$$
Ax=0
$$
has a notrivial solution if and only if $\det A=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you set up the corresponding augmented coefficient matrix, you'll see that the matrix has determinant $$\left(\sin{(2\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}\cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)} - \cos{(2\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}\sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}\right)$$

We want the determinant to be zero in order to ensure there is a non-trivial solution.